# Can I change the "no interent connection" page with a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, offline

I was wondering if it is possible through a Chrome extension to go to edit the page with the dinosaur game, which is shown in absent connection. I would like to modify that game. I also wondered if I also have to make a piece of special to make it work offline.

Comment: Chrome extensions cannot change chrome's default pages. Only the new tab.

Comment: i suppose you can add request handler and redirect all requests to your page when there is no connection

Comment: Ok thanks @Pavel Agarkov, I'll try to see if it works for my purpose